# What battery connector type is this?

Tags: batteries, identification, connector, plug

Just spent a long time on the JST site and the Molex site trying to identify the following connector. It's got 2mm pitch and is used for a battery connector in a small RC quadcopter.

I found them on AliExpress listed as "MX 2mm" at https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000639410772.html. MX = Molex?

This UK site here http://www.micronradiocontrol.co.uk/conn_molex2mm.html simple named them "Molex 2mm".

Yet, I scrolled through the entire [Molex 2mm pitch catalogue](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/deepSearch?pQuery=q%253D*%253A*%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcollection%253Aimpulse%2540fq%253Dcategory%253A%2522Cable%252BAssemblies%2522%2540fq%253D&currentQuery=pitchmatinginterface%3A2.00mm&origin=_l1stv13w) but none was even close.

[image][image]

Comment: Given the fishy electrical tape and the hard to find connector, why not just cut the wires and replace it with something easier to obtain?

Answer (score 3):

After I posted the Q I came across https://connectorbook.com/identification.html. It helped me identify this as Molex (indeed) 51006 + 51005.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for coming back with the answer to your question. Since you must [wait 48 hours after you asked the question](/help/self-answer) before you can accept your own answer, please come back and accept your answer (or another one, if an even better answer is posted in the meantime) after 20:49 UTC on 6 April. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, that's my site! I am glad you discovered it!

Comment: @DavideAndrea Exactly, I found it an an answer of yours for a different question.